# Postgres - Peer authentication - psql: FATAL: role "xxxx" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, sockets

I know there are plenty of posts with close message. I've read hopefully all. And did not find the answer. Some offer to use `-h localhost` to jump from `local` to `host` rules in `hba.conf`. Some say to set `trust` on `local`... But I want `peer` authentication, not over `TCP` and not trusted!

so I have user vao on both `OS` AND `DB`:

```
t=# \! who am i
vao      pts/8        2016-11-11 12:23 (10.1.10.158)

t=# \du+ vao
                  List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of | Description
-----------+------------+-----------+-------------
 vao       | Superuser  | {}        |
```

and yet when I try to psql I get error:

```
$ psql t
psql: FATAL:  role "vao" does not exist
```

According to [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html)

> The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's
>   operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed
>   database user name (with optional user name mapping). This method is
>   only supported on local connections.

and

> Peer authentication is only available on operating systems providing
>   the getpeereid() function, the SO_PEERCRED socket parameter, or
>   similar mechanisms. Currently that includes Linux, most flavors of BSD
>   including OS X, and Solaris.

So I look if Debian supports getpeereid()
or SO_PEERCRED and desperately dig for explanation.

Until I realyze I hit obvious lack of environment set. If psql doesn't find user, maybe it doesn't find a `socket`?..
So I check `unix_socket_directories` in `postgresql.conf`
and according to 
psql manual:

> --host=hostname
>        Specifies the host name of the machine on which the server is
>        running. If the value begins with a slash, it is used as the
>        directory for the Unix-domain socket.

try `psql t -h '/path/to/unix_socket_directories'` and voila - I'm there

And this is not the first time I step on this rake!
So I post it here - hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

**The error is misleading.**

instead of

> psql: FATAL:  role "xxx" does not exist

should be

> psql: FATAL:  socket "yyy" does not exist

or anything else, that would lead us to the idea, that the we lack [Environment Variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html)

so smth like `export PGHOST=/var/run/postgresql` will cure the ilness